# Запрос на вывод фамилии человека, который дольше всех находился в больнице SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

наткнулся на проблему. Нужно сделать 2 запроса в Access
 1. Вывести фамилию человека, который дольше всех находился в больнице.
 2. Информацию о больных, которые поступили в прошлом месяце.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался сделать запрос в стиле:

```
SELECT *
FROM Больные
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,[Дата вписки],[Дата виписка]);
```

Но он не работает, может кто подскажет в чем ошибка, либо другой вариант?
Так же пытался сделать второй запрос

```
Select *
From Больные
Where [Дата вписки] = DateAdd("m", -1, Date());
```

Но тоже не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Больные
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,[Дата вписки],[Дата виписка]) DESC

Comment: Большое спасибо. Отлично работает.
Не подскажите по второму запросу?

Comment: По второму вопросу:
SELECT *
FROM Больные
WHERE datepart("m",[Дата вписки])=datepart("m",date())-1

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы хотите выводить фамилию пациента то как минимум нужно писать так:

```
SELECT [ПІБ]
FROM Больные
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,[Дата вписки],[Дата виписка]);
```

А во втором запросе используйте конструкцию LIKE:

```
--Вывести информацию о пациентах которые поступили в прошлом месяце
SELECT *
FROM Больные
WHERE [Дата вписки] LIKE '??.[номер месяца].%'
```

Comment: запрос требует ввести значение dd)

Comment: а что такое dd?

Comment: Это аргумент DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) , пробовал dd и day, но всеравно просит ввести значение